# How to convert two arrays to a key-value pair and append them to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a project in which I need an array like this:

```
user = [{
"name": "foo",
"email": "foo@foo.com"
},{
"name": "bar",
"email": "bar@bar.com"
},]
```

the values name and email are in two separate arrays, like:

```
names=[foo,bar];
mails=[foo@foo.com,bar@bar.com]
```

How do I convert these two arrays in a single array of objects with predefined keys name and email?

I am trying something like this:

```
var user = [];
    for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        user[i].name = names[i];
        user[i].email = mails[i];
    }
```

but this raises an error that name property is not defined.

Comment: It's a simple `for` loop that pushes objects onto the result array. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: @isherwood It's nothing like that question.

Comment: @isherwood He doesn't have an array of keys. Both arrays contain values, and they go into different properties in the resulting array.

Comment: @Barmar I havent tried anything ..can you help?

Comment: No, that's not how the site works. You try to solve the problem yourself. If you can't get it working, you post your attempt and we'll help you fix it. If you want someone to write code for you, hire a programmer.

Comment: @NenadVracar He wants to go the opposite way. He's starting with the `names` and `email` arrays, he wants to get `user`.

Comment: I worked on a solution for this and now I can't answer the question, haha.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to push an object composed of mames and email this way

```
var names=["foo","bar"];
var mails=["foo@foo.com","bar@bar.com"];
var users = [];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++) users.push({"name" : names[i], "email" : mails[i]});
console.log(users); 

Run:
[ { name: 'foo', email: 'foo@foo.com' },
{ name: 'bar', email: 'bar@bar.com' } ]
```